# How to reduce image size captured from cam

Tags: iphone, ios

The Picture taken from the iphone cam is nearly 2.5 Mb, How to reduce this size ,I have tried
UIJPEGRepresentation(image,0.1f),but it does not effect the size ?

Comment: @Foram Mukund Shah-My question is How to reduce the Image Size in terms of memory ,Now it means Reduce image size interms of dimensions.Why did u edit the question ?

Comment: when you try to reduce image "size", it becomes self explanatory that you want to reduce in terms of memory only, otherwise you could have reduce it either from xib or programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't reduce the size the images takes up in memory.

When an image is loaded, basically a `UIImage` object the size wil be width x height x 4 bytes. That is the size the an uncompressed image will take up in memory.
Since you can use compressed images all image, once loaded in a `UIImage` will be uncompressed.

If you really need so save some memory, save the image to disk and create a thumbnail which you use in your app. Then when need you can load the larger image and use it,

Comment: @rckoenes-Thanks for your reply .How to create a thumbnail view ? Should i resize the image to a particular height and width ?

Comment: Well you create a new image, wich has different dimensions, with for example the with the code that [@Meet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/942110/meet) has posted. Thus you will have to save two images in the end, one full one and one thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Resize method in UIImage+Resize.h

https://github.com/AliSoftware/UIImage-Resize

```
 [aImgView setImage:[ImageObjectFromPicker resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit bounds:YourSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh]];
```

Comment: This is resizing the image i am looking forward,how to reduce the memory size of the image taken ....@Meet

Comment: @ROY, Resizing the image will reduce its size to your desired size